# Using WPF code in Windows 10, how do you obtain all the windows (Not just the top level window) of currently running programs?

Tags: c#, wpf, process

I am currently working on an app switcher program that would need to switch between all the windows of running applications (not just the top level window) in Windows 10. Is this possible in WPF?

So far, I have tried iterating through each process obtained from calling Process.GetProcesses().

```
Process[] processList = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach(Process process in processList){
  // code 
}
```

By using that API, I have only been able to get the MainWindowHandle and MainWindowTitle from the process object. Instead, I would actually like to get the title of a window that is not in the top level as well.

For example:
If I have two windows of Google Chrome open, I would have access to the titles of each of the windows instead of just the top-level or most recently used window.

So far, I've looked into using [EnumWindows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows), but I noticed that in Windows 10 that will only return the top-level window.

Comment: You need to use [`EnumChildWindows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumchildwindows) in addition to `EnumWindows`.

Comment: I noticed another example on StackOverflow that uses EnumChildWindows.  

https://gist.github.com/ijcuevas2/1baaa50eb7ba8a975c2644263589dac7.  

At the end, the variable windowTitles (I think) is supposed to hold the title of each window.  

However, if I have two windows of chrome open. I get the title of the main window (same as using Process.MainWindowTitle), and I noticed another title named "Chrome Helper" which is not the name of the non-main window I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [EnumChildWindows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumchildwindows).

This should more or less look like that:

First, create a helper class for WinApi:

```
class WindowManager
{
    public delegate bool EnumWindowProc(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr window, EnumWindowProc callback, IntPtr lParam);


    //this one would iterate through child windows of window
    public static bool IterateChildWindows(IntPtr window, EnumWindowProc callback, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        return EnumChildWindows(window, callback, lParam);
    }

}
```

Now, you can call IterateChildWindows. OnEnumWindow is the method that will be called on every window found. Note that window is also a button, textbox, etc:

```
WindowManager.IterateChildWindows(hwnd, OnEnumWindow, IntPtr.Zero);

bool OnEnumWindow(IntPtr foundWindow, IntPtr lParam)
{

   //here you have to check if this window is a form or a control and then do your work           
}
```